# android start activity on conditions

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activities that needs starting based on a condition. It is very similar to the login scenario. like:

1. if users are not logged in, go to login activity. after correct authentication, go to a profile activity.
2. if users are already logged in, go to the profile activity directly.

**update:** I thought about redirecting at login activity, but if users hit back button it go back to the log in activity, I don't want this to happen.

how can this be achieved? thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to do it. You mentioned the first one: from the `Login` activity launch the second activity if user is already logged in, **but** call the `finish` method of the Login activity after you have started the second one. That way users won't be able to go back to the login activity.

The other one is to create a third activity, called `LauncherActivity` or something like that. From that activity you decide which activity to launch. In this case you will also have to use the finish method to kill the `LauncherActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

Create an activity with no Ui which will deal with this decision in Oncreate and then call finish() in the Oncreate itself. So that this activity will not be launched on back key press. 
Also Add android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" to this Activity so that you will not have it giving black screen

Answer (score 2):

I liked the idea with finishing activities i would do the same thing, but also i would suggest to to add permissions to your activities to prevent calling them directly using startActivity() method.

Comment: just simply define your own permission in manifest and add it to your activity. You can find here  all the necessary info about doing that http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

Answer (score 1):

In your launcher activity deal with this conditions. For 1 start one intent, and for 2 another. For preventing back-button scenario, override onKeyDown in your launcher activity.